# running a pipe command with variable substitution on remote host

Tags: bash, ssh

I'd to run a piped command with variable substitution on a remote host and redirect the output. Given that the login shell is csh, I have to used "bash -c". With help from users nlrc and jerdiggity, a command with no variable substitution can be formulated as:

```
localhost$ ssh -f -q remotehost 'bash -c "ls /var/tmp/ora_flist.sh|xargs -L1 cat >/var/tmp/1"'
```

but the single quote above will preclue using variable substitution, say, substituting ora_flist.sh for $filename. how can I accomplish that?

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing.  Are your just trying to execute a script in remote host using ssh?

Comment: I think you will need to quote the bash command: `ssh -q remotehost 'bash -c "..."'`

Comment: you are right. that worked. but I have another request: I'd like to be able to use variable substitution in the remote command. the single quote will preclude that. any better idea?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
ssh -f -q remotehost 'bash -c "ls /var/tmp/ora_flist.sh|xargs -L1 cat >/var/tmp/1"'
```

Comment: that's good. I have one more in my wishlist: I'd like to be able to use variable substitution in the remote command. i.e., replace ora_flist.sh with $filename, the single quote will preclude that. any better idea?

Comment: Well, any content inside double quotes is the subject of variable expansion, while single quotes prevent the expansion.

Answer (score 0):

So your problem was that you want the shell variable to be extended locally. Just leave it outside the single quotes, e.g.

```
ssh -f -q remotehost 'bash -c "ls '$filename' | xargs ..."'
```

Also very useful trick to avoid the quoting hell is to use heredoc, e.g.

```
ssh -f -q remotehost <<EOF
bash -c "ls $filename | xargs ... "
EOF
```